# Java concurrentmodificationexception in priority queue

Tags: java, iterator, priority-queue, concurrentmodification

I have a problem iterating my priority queue which cost Concurrentmodificationexception.

code for iterating:

```
Queue<Patient> pq = new PriorityQueue<Patient>();
 Iterator<Patient> it = pq.iterator();    
            while(iter.hasNext()){
                Patient current = iter.next();
                if(current.getName().equals(patientName)){

                    pq.remove(p);
                    }


                }
```

There error says that iter.next() cost Concurrentmodificationexception. 
May i please know how to resolve this? i have search the internet but the still cant find a solution to this.

Comment: You can't delete an element of the queue which you are actually iterating.

Comment: you can't remove elements from iterator

Comment: Use `iter.remove();` to remove while iteracting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to following for solving it -

```
Queue<Patient> pq = new PriorityQueue<Patient>();
 Iterator<Patient> iter = pq.iterator();    
            while(iter.hasNext()){
                Patient current = iter.next();
                if(current.getName().equals(patientName)){

                    iter.remove();
                    }


                }
```

**Explanation** `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown from next() method of iterator, if there is any structural change in the underlying collection (in your case Queue) i.e. any element is added or removed in the queue directly. It is called `Fail Fast Iterator`.

Comment: iter ... it... :)

Comment: Thank You @Vikas Sachdeva!! it works! may i know why? thanks!

Comment: you don't want to Explain ? copying and pasting code with modifing it will not help to learn ...

Comment: ConcurrentModificationException is thrown  if there is any structural change in the queue (underlying collection of iterator) i.e.any element is added or removed in the queue directly. This is called Fail Fast Iterator

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ConcurrentLinkedQueue instead of PriorityQueue

Acording to: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html

> Beware that, unlike in most collections, the size method is NOT a constant-time operation. Because of the asynchronous nature of these queues, determining the current number of elements requires a traversal of the elements, and so may report inaccurate results if this collection is modified during traversal.

Comment: what's that ? can you explain more ? prefered to be with an example

Answer (score 0):

Since Java8, you can remove using `removeIf` which is part of `Collection` contract.

Given that `removeIf` method takes a predicate, your code could be as simple as :

```
priorityQueue.removeIf(patient -> patient.getName().equals(patientName));
```

As for the Concurrent exception you had, this simply happened because you tried to remove calling `PriorityQueue#remove` directly while you were already iterating which would make the iterator obsolete. The proper way to remove when iterating is by using `Iterator#next` and then `Iterator#remove` (this is actually what de default implementation of `removeIf` does).